# R - GAM regressions (mgcv) response curves change shape/direction when adding new variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam, mgcv

I am using a GAM (using the mgcv package) to look at the variation of abundances of one organism with respect to several environmental variables.

My data looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

Station abd Temperature Oxygen  Salinity
crossing_01_st02    343.199 10.880389   222.62732   33.24007
crossing_01_st03    3427.2116   9.896878    170.52723   33.60561
crossing_01_st04    2091.7223   10.325418   146.88088   33.71725
crossing_01_st05    3365.6303   10.447803   152.83051   33.71425
crossing_01_st06    4895.5442   10.858568   168.23048   33.68162
crossing_01_st07    4785.7697   10.221149   142.10408   33.75456
crossing_01_st08    4739.7415   10.307083   139.84557   33.78507
crossing_01_st10    3930.383    9.624018    123.82912   33.81374
crossing_01_st11    5710.4398   9.513673    124.79245   33.80772
crossing_01_st12    8213.8983   9.314383    122.80188   33.83794
crossing_01_st13    6175.7285   9.268011    135.29098   33.83685
crossing_02_st01    5952.9914   9.055155    95.48518    33.9358
crossing_02_st03    2696.3755   9.335852    116.52235   33.85236
crossing_02_st04    4072.1314   9.754846    138.25631   33.77391
crossing_02_st05    2394.5551   9.597139    128.31808   33.77155
crossing_02_st06    1744.0551   9.774439    149.00231   33.65033
crossing_02_st07    1427.5309   9.535947    176.11583   33.54753
crossing_02_st08    541.8052    10.005704   197.96463   33.40531
crossing_02_st09    173.3703    10.205607   206.16945   33.36126
crossing_02_st10    456.3426    10.622767   221.5186    33.26646
cycle_01_cast01 6823.9262   9.786862    116.12442   33.85257
cycle_01_cast02 7400.7068   9.785606    120.85602   33.83325
cycle_01_cast03 5343.2857   10.158589   139.62563   33.77581
cycle_01_cast04 5561.953    9.689744    139.47995   33.76726
cycle_01_cast05 6855.6716   9.267254    138.03602   33.79975
cycle_01_cast06 6859.4645   9.791765    134.7162    33.76183
cycle_02_cast01 330.9797    10.746551   208.04335   33.33226
cycle_02_cast03 231.1604    10.616365   209.49808   33.31173
cycle_02_cast04 544.3918    10.565562   205.8037    33.34717
cycle_02_cast05 235.6214    10.38223    197.70585   33.39902
cycle_02_cast07 182.0388    10.540305   208.21308   33.33308
cycle_02_cast08_2   1187.5021   10.414415   201.71851   33.37685
cycle_02_cast09 1656.9597   9.978496    186.95632   33.48471
cycle_03_cast01 4816.7298   9.416381    100.71815   33.90358
cycle_03_cast02 5514.5958   9.427468    101.28535   33.90143
cycle_03_cast03 4436.9845   9.528815    107.20829   33.88003
cycle_03_cast04 5334.6542   9.40963 117.85671   33.82466
cycle_03_cast05 8826.6174   9.410874    116.09786   33.82881
cycle_03_cast06 8792.56 9.257086    111.92037   33.84714
cycle_03_cast08 8110.7264   9.372722    123.3256    33.82041
cycle_04_cast01 211.0595    11.554293   230.22028   33.20413
cycle_04_cast04 179.7914    11.197575   225.20708   33.23228
cycle_04_cast05 166.5575    11.393151   226.56168   33.21736
cycle_04_cast06 147.1021    11.379475   228.57757   33.20565
cycle_04_cast07 138.6963    11.339498   226.59277   33.21873
cycle_05_cast01 617.0933    10.538117   195.79625   33.49209
cycle_05_cast02 763.2103    9.854859    181.83223   33.50503
cycle_05_cast03 1454.6652   10.719085   208.2208    33.40604
cycle_05_cast04 940.1714    10.695348   211.12725   33.35623
cycle_05_cast05 984.9135    11.114098   214.13466   33.42644
p1408_008   429.6539    9.955556    117.60191   33.79807
p1408_009   551.5781    10.109037   129.78458   33.71664
p1408_010   1090.7607   10.096017   139.46102   33.64799
p1408_011   1008.6421   9.773443    121.056 33.7683
p1408_012   1018.451    10.009549   127.55012   33.72919
p1408_013   1478.1  9.837543    132.82643   33.71031
p1408_014   634.3147    9.171992    143.98665   33.69484
p1408_019   1261.4535   9.925149    144.02358   33.66018
p1408_020   895.1759    10.281067   157.89194   33.57496
p1408_021   894.1513    9.941134    137.3812    33.70525
p1408_022   1013.2815   10.012316   133.53466   33.71364
p1408_023   1465.2027   9.998437    132.7186    33.72103
p1408_024   1387.3383   10.023705   133.01306   33.70337
p1408_025   1131.3854   9.798109    126.38143   33.77076
p1408_026   1920.4206   9.796771    124.29865   33.78191
p1408_027   1518.2211   9.706037    115.40608   33.83985
p1408_028   1351.4425   9.71432 115.06117   33.83702
p1408_029   1776.763    9.819473    123.35006   33.7771
p1408_032   169.5453    9.601247    182.55748   33.46663
p1408_033   185.7481    9.459888    188.18871   33.44482
p1408_034   533.2673    9.805629    167.51825   33.50092
p1408_035   918.7359    9.430061    180.51512   33.49057
p1408_036   257.1976    9.674115    171.3   33.51555
p1408_037   905.7629    9.676409    171.52495   33.49375
p1408_038   867.7851    9.408992    161.45491   33.59505
p1408_039   597.6163    9.68413 188.2719    33.4009
p1408_040   1785.0849   9.474682    170.19411   33.54021
p1408_041   668.1221    9.448858    177.52229   33.506
p1408_051   166.1487    10.980822   216.65745   33.16259
p1408_056   106.383 11.867383   228.92551   33.0945
p1408_058   226.3468    12.124444   228.97567   33.08706
p1604_02    2527.2334   12.074301   199.61586   33.28931
p1604_03    3380.0072   11.922921   195.74938   33.30905
p1604_05    3675.7893   11.671741   188.88949   33.33841
p1604_09    3453.929    11.735068   190.83477   33.34591
p1604_10    1189.6463   12.264773   218.65712   33.18436
p1604_11    1196.9789   12.450878   220.982 33.1585
p1604_12    2027.3274   11.793328   210.32928   33.21888
p1604_13    1441.1081   12.653082   222.26812   33.17408
p1604_14    963.5869    12.326745   219.86165   33.17834
p1604_15    1613.0636   12.393148   219.8886    33.14464
p1604_16    658.4892    12.750862   223.2642    33.14848
p1604_17    1309.0813   12.471335   221.47351   33.15247
p1604_18    1354.5372   12.216455   218.88083   33.12412
p1604_19    1434.5431   12.657842   221.77662   33.1185
p1604_20    1062.6206   12.322844   220.29652   33.14848
p1604_21    1941.8302   12.782927   224.20348   33.089
p1604_23    3401.0905   10.280862   182.66022   33.51492
p1604_24    3502.4929   9.71893 163.12155   33.5462
p1604_25    4742.5206   9.772787    158.93855   33.55103
p1604_26    5364.7968   9.767572    151.34155   33.62338
p1604_27    3940.3145   9.472281    165.1516    33.6148
p1604_29    5670.4874   9.677677    169.85598   33.54579
p1604_30    4986.9538   9.987309    180.425 33.50413
p1604_33    5215.7347   9.530931    170.52985   33.57246
p1604_36    3154.6535   9.472636    110.74072   33.86774
p1604_37    3598.488    9.155606    101.19137   33.93614
p1604_38    3733.3041   9.238361    109.37808   33.87358
p1604_39    3777.4703   9.34017 112.88268   33.84185
p1604_40    4474.8835   9.165892    108.03168   33.88497
p1604_42    4838.1334   8.980138    109.30434   33.89938
p1604_43    4931.4312   8.925082    107.71142   33.91524
p1604_45    6332.5305   8.927316    111.68705   33.88828
```

Before running the GAM, I ran a simple graphical check-up to see how my abundances vary with the variables. Using `ggplot`, the code would look like this:

```
df %>%
  gather(variable, value, -Station, -abd) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = abd)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(aes(color = "lm"), method = "lm", geom = 'line') +
  stat_smooth(aes(color = "gam"), method = "gam",  formula = y ~ s(x),geom = 'line') +
  scale_y_log10() +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw()
```

And provides me this graph:

[image: ggplot_output]

...where I can see trends for each of the variables. For example, I can see that my abundances seem to be decreasing with increasing temperature, and there is a monotonic decrease of abundances with increasing oxygen.

-
Now when running the GAM, I am hitting some weird responses.
A first glance, I would run the GAM like this:

```
library(mgcv)

df.gam <- gam(log10(abd) ~ s(Oxygen) + s(Temperature) + s(Salinity), data = df, method = "REML")
```

The output tells me that all three variables have significant effects and altogether explain 74% of deviance. But where it gets 'problematic' is when I plot the response curves (either using plot, or here using `visreg`).

```
library(visreg)

visreg(df.gam, scale = "response", rug = F, line = list(lwd = 1))
```

Now the curves behave completely different from the `ggplot` and `stat_smooth` output (even without the `stat_smooth`, I could say that the predicted curve does not fit the data???)

[image: visreg_output]

To add more complexity, if I run a univariate GAM on each of the variables one by one and look at their response curves, they actually agree with the `ggplot` output.

Is this difference due to the additive nature of the GAM, for example meaning that the response of my abundance to temperature would be different (basically going from decreasing to increasing...) if I add the effect of oxygen or salinity? Or is this some kind of odd response from the `gam` function?

Comment: My intuition is that there is correlation among your predictor values - have you checked to see what happens if you graph 02 vs temp, and both vs salinity?This would explain why the results for the analysis with all 3 are different than doing them one at a time.

Comment: You are comparing univariate relationships with multivariately adjusted ones. Of course they are different. If they were not different there would be no point in using multivariate methods. You need to consult a statistician if this is related to any sort of research with a monetary or policy impact. Within the StackExchange universe there is CrossValidated.com.

Comment: @42- I don't argue on the difference between uni- & multivariate approaches, I just have a hard time explaining the ecological meaning of the GAM prediction. On one hand I have plots telling me that increasing temperature led to decrease in abundances. On the other, hand, the GAM tells me the complete opposite and it is going against any previous observations. I have run other GAM on similar dataset and never got this flip in curves, so my question was more whether statistical effects (maybe correlation? cf. John Paul post) could explain this?

Comment: Asking us to untangle your data relationships without actually presenting the data is completely off-topic for SO. Each of those GAM plots is done with the other variables held at a constant value, so the interdependency of `abd` on the three variables is not well examined. Furthermore, this code depends on packages not loaded with library calls so probably not useful to future readers. I would be using some of the 2d smooths in mgcv to understand the complexities, but without the data, not much can be demonstrated. So still think this question needs to be closed.

Comment: @42- Apologies, I was not fully aware about the difference between SO and CrossValidated. I have edited the question adding 1) the full dataset and 2) library call. Going back to the original problem, further analysis of variable revealed correlation between the variables. Dropping variable seems too arbitrary and I tried to figure out the use of tensor product to deal with covariates.

Answer (score 1):

Retracted my close vote. Using the `te()` function on the two variables that displayed evidence of puzzling relationships, Oxygen and Temperature, and calling for `plot.gam` on the result, one can where the interactions is anything but linear.

```
df.gam <- gam(log10(abd) ~ te(Oxygen, Temperature) + s(Salinity), data = df,
                method = "REML")

#-----
> ?plot.gam
> plot(df.gam)
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
```

[image]

```
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
```

[image]

Both O<sub>2</sub>  and temp would be expected to enhance growth or abundance, but the solubility of oxygen in liquid water is inversely proportional to temperature, so such a relationship seems plausible.